# javascript command in the browser url to pop alert up

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want the browser to send an alert saying "hello" when I put the following in my url:

[image: https://puu.sh/D4TY3/2a2f8e82dc.png]

I have tried:

`javascript://(function(){alert('this is a bookmarklet';})()`

also tried it like:

```
javascript:(function(){alert('this is a bookmarklet';})()
```

I'm expecting an alert pop up and instead nothing is happening. Is it because I have an adblocker? does that disable popups like this.

EDIT

No, just disabled my adblocker and its still not working.

I am annoyed because this seems like a really good way for me to actually make my javascript tinkering useful.

Comment: You might consider using a userscript instead

Comment: This is a simple typo. Both examples have a `;` and `}` in the wrong place. You have `{alert(x;})` when you need `{alert(x);}`. You're also missing a closing `)`.

Comment: You typoed, your code has a missing )

Answer (score 1):

All of these will be valid:

`javascript:alert('this is a bookmarklet');`

`javascript:(function(){alert('this is a bookmarklet');})()`

`javascript:(()=>alert('this is a bookmarklet');)()`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Just use `alert`, no need for an IIFE:

```js
window.location = "javascript:alert('This is a bookmarklet')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste in browser url:
`data:text/html,<script>alert('This is a bookmarklet');</script>`